# How to send query parameters in a sequence (order) using http get method (Angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send 3 parameters in url for get method.

```
getUser: function(auser) { 
                          var config = {
                          params: {
                             UserName: 'User89@domain170.com',
                            CorrelationId: '01233',
                            OrganizationId: '428'
                    }
                }

                  //API Call
            var promise = $http.get(API_URL, config, REQUEST_HEADER).then(
            function(aGetUserResponse) { // return}
```

But I am getting 404 because my parameters are not sending in correct order. Why my order is changing? Any solution for this?

```
http://127.0.0.0:8000/client_01/users?CorrelationId=01233&OrganizationId=428&UserName=User89@domain170.com
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Order shouldn't matter if your API endpoint is done correctly.  Can you post your server side code for the "/client_01/users" endpoint?

Comment: The order does not and should not matter. If you depend on the order of the query string parameters then something else is wrong. Objects in JavaScript do not have an order. That is to say the order is not guaranteed. What you are seeing here is the alphanumeric order in which some browsers are implemented.

Comment: If your endpoint is relying on parameter order I'd say that's bad.  There's now guarantee that the bowser will send them in any order.  Like @big_water said it might be nice to see your back end too

Comment: I am testing from soap UI and if I change parameter sequence I get  404.
If I give exact url like this  then it works and give me response. "127.0.0.0:8000/client_01/users?UserName=User89@domain170.com&CorrelationId=01233&OrganizationId=428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of the matter is, your server side code should be setup in a way that query parameter order in the query string does not matter.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10005639/5481661) is a good explanation on the matter.

If you have access to the server side code that parses the parameters, the changes should really be made there. We can help with that if you share that code with us. It's really not a a problem with your angular code.  If you don't have access to the code, I would suggest manually formatting the query string instead of letting Angulars $http service do it for you. Such as:

```
getUser: 
function(auser) { 
    var config = {
        params: {
        }
    }
}

function queryUrl(username, corrId, orgId){
    return API_URL + "?UserName=" + username 
            + "&CorrelationId=" + corrId
            + "&OrganizationId=" + orgId;
}

//API Call
var promise = $http.get(queryUrl(), config, REQUEST_HEADER).then(
function(aGetUserResponse) { // return}
```

Comment: I do not have access to that and how can I manually format query string?

Comment: @M.Khan i have made an edit to show an example of how you could do it manually.