# Zuul filter parameter order

Tags: java

My request is like this http://localhost:8080/app/app-name?param1=val&param2=val2&param3=val3

But i can see at the server logs that param3 is coming first, parma2 and param 1

I should follow the order, how can it possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317281/ordering-of-values-in-httpservletrequest-getparametervalues) for another post about this same topic.

Ideally, your application logic should be structured where the ordering of the request's query parameters does not matter. See the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005335/how-does-position-of-parameters-in-a-query-string-affect-the-page/10005639#10005639/).

With respect to defining a filter for Zuul, you are able to access the query parameters through the RequestContext available to you as follows (additional example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/#_add_a_filter)):

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
Map<String, List<String>> queryParams = ctx.getRequestQueryParams();
```

Alternatively:

```
String queryString = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getQueryString();
```

will retrieve the query string but it is dependent upon the servlet specification if it retains an ordering on the query parameters or not - which to my understanding there is no / hasn't been any guarantee on the ordering.

See [here](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=java+servlet) for the servlet specification you are interested in.